# Angle arms fitting to data points

Tags: python, r, regression, curve-fitting, angle

I would like to fit "angle arms" to data points in R.

Main assumption about data is that y values increase quite significantly at the beginning, and after some time increase is remarkably slower (something like a plateau with deviations).

Is it possible to determine x coordinate of such point (angle vertex) without specific assumptions?
My idea is to divide x range to two parts and perform linear regression to fit angle arms.

Picture shows two possible angle vertexes (yellow/red) that looks quite good for me (straight line/empty circles is linear regression fit for the all data).
Solid blue circles/points represent input data. Green bold lines are my subjective angle arms fit to the data.

[Angle fit example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHLSP.png)

Comment: Would splitting the data into two sets, each with its own linear regression, be of any use in your work?

Comment: Yes, I want to perform linear regression in two sets/segments and I need independent method to find vertex (data split into two segments) at the beginning.
I have over 200 records, sometimes it is quite hard to decide where put the vertex (split the data).
I wonder if it is possible to determine such split automatically without any special assumptions besides general/expected shape of the plots.
Data can be scattered and there can be many "flat stairs" (3 stairs in the example).

Comment: I have a graphical Python example that does exactly what you describe, would posting the Python code be OK?

Comment: Yes, I've added Python tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, here is a graphical Python example that fits two straight lines to data with the breakpoint between them automatically selected as a fitted parameter. This example uses the standard scipy differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to determine initial parameter estimates for both the two straight lines and the breakpoint. That scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds withing which to search. In this example, those bounds are derived from the input data.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(xArray, breakpoint, slopeA, offsetA, slopeB, offsetB):
    returnArray = []
    for x in xArray:
        if x < breakpoint:
            returnArray.append(slopeA * x + offsetA)
        else:
            returnArray.append(slopeB * x + offsetB)
    return returnArray


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)
    slope = 10.0 * (maxY - minY) / (maxX - minX) # times 10 for safety margin

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for breakpoint
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeA
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetA
    parameterBounds.append([-slope, slope]) # search bounds for slopeB
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offsetB


    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# call curve_fit without passing bounds from genetic algorithm
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete code example. I've applied this method to my data and breakpoint (vertex) position looks quite good.